# How to group floats in to bins?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have array `(1000*1)` of floats ranging from `0` to `1500.5`.
e.g. `100.0, 1.1, 505.3, 0.0, 210.1` and so on

I want to put them in a group with width 10 like below.

```
1.1   --> 10
505.3 --> 510
0.1 --> 10
210.1 --> 220
```

How can I do this mapping efficiently?

Comment: Do you basically just want to round up to the next 10? Which bin/group should e.g. 504 be mapped to?

Comment: yes, more of binning, 504 will be mapped to 510.

Answer (score 1):

A basic way is to floor divide all of numbers by `10`, add `1` and multiply them by `10` again.

```
a = [12, 23, 34, 46, 57, 521]
print([(i // 10 + 1) * 10 for i in a])
```

as a function:

```
def round_up(the_list):
    return [(i // 10 + 1) * 10 for i in the_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at link below. Create histogram with numpy

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html

If you want visualisation look at matplotlib library

Answer (score 0):

If you are only interested in calculating the [`ceil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.ceil)ed mappings, a very basic approach could be:

```
import math

numbers = [1.1, 505.3, 0.1, 210.1]
results = {n: math.ceil(n/10)*10 for n in numbers}

print(results)
# --> {1.1: 10, 505.3: 510, 0.1: 10, 210.1: 220}
```

Comment: It works partially. My array length is 10000 but results length is only 286.

Comment: I used a `dict` to demonstrate the mapping, easily. However, dicts are not able to handle duplicate keys. I would assume you do have duplicate values in your array, but only 286 unique values. Alternatively, you can use a list which will not ignore duplicates: `results = [math.ceil(n/10)*10 for n in numbers]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import math
from collections import defaultdict

rand_float = np.random.uniform(low=0.1, high=35, size=(7,))

bin = defaultdict(list)

for v in rand_float:
    bin[(v // 10)*10].append(v)

print(bin)
```

Res:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {
10.0: [13.481283363231569, 17.499084832032626, 19.64083471546001], 
0.0: [7.575742141494037, 7.520094038776975, 8.05852627042683], 
20.0: [21.661914893465095]})
```